# Cannot copy files from EC2 in VPC to S3 with EC2 role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc

From an EC2 instance running within a VPC I am in need of accessing an S3 bucket with awscli for copying files from EC2 to S3.

I succesfully created an endpoint with an attached custom policy built with the policy builder supplied by Amazon.

The EC2 is running with a specific role, if I assign such role "ARN:..." to principal I am receiving "Access Denied". If I replace the role with "*" it works perfectly. What I am doing wrong ? This the policy, as you see I am allowing only the upload and retrieve of objects:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy14467516498654",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1446751649837",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*" <-- it's not working with specific role
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:CreateMultipartUpload"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::thebucket/thechildbucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The role has full EC2 Access. I have already tried to assign full S3 access, but  it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The policy on the role itself has to have the S3:[permissions] access to the destination bucket as well.

```
{
        "Sid": "Stmt1234",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            ""arn:aws:s3:::thebucket/thechildbucket",
            ""arn:aws:s3:::thebucket/thechildbucket/*"

        ]
    }
```